# ROS 2D costmap layer to avoid certain areas

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap

I am trying to implement a costmap layer which would allow a robot to assign higher costs to unfavorable terrain, like patches of grass. So, the robot is still able to pass over the grass if that is what the best path involves, but it will usually try to stay off the grass if it can.

Is there any code which already implements this? I see that the ROS wiki says, "For example, if a user wants to express that a robot should attempt to avoid a particular area of a building, they may inset their own costs into the costmap for that region independent of any obstacles", so I think it should be possible.